# report: group account activity by accounting period instead of by month

Tags: taxes, gnucash, annual-report

I'm using GnuCash 2.6.12 and would like to create an annual report for tax reporting purposes. For that, I would like to create a report where transactions are grouped for the whole year, (the accounting period) but instead, I get them grouped by month. How can I change this?
Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Are you looking for a transaction list or P&L, or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to 3.7.

It has Multicolumn Balance Sheet & Income Statements in the Experimental reports submenu.

Alternatively try Transaction Report sorting/grouping tab.